# How can I avoid indexing multiple equivalent entities with hibernate search?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate search and I would like to do special things.

On the update of a person entity, the method that persist the entity duplicate this one + create new person entity.
Which means that I'm standing with 3 person entity after an update of this person. (Because I'm versioning all the data in the db).

Is there a way to avoid the indexation of the duplicate element in the hibernate search index?

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate search index works closely with your mapping. If you have it via annotations or xml files, it does not matter. You have to specify `unique property` via one of those methods.
I use hbm.xml files so my configuration `unique="true"`.

The index is maintained based on your persisted objects. You should have scheduled job that optimizes it every once in a while.

If you post some POJO, you are concerned about, I can be more specific with an example.